# Get short term AWS CLI Credentials from SSO KeyCloak SAML Provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak, aws-cli, saml-2.0, aws-sts

```sh
aws sts assume-role-with-saml \
    --role-arn=arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/team-developers 
    --principal-arn=arn:aws:iam::xxx:saml-provider \
    --saml-assertion ""
```

So how do I get the value for **saml-assertion**?

I can authorize through KeyCloak SSO with the role, but need to get AWS credentials for that role.

How do I do that?

Comment: I would try to use SAML tracer extension in the browser to get SAML response, when you log in through browser. That base 64 encoded saml response, should be payload for --saml-assertion. Maybe also SAML ecp may give good SAML response.

Comment: thank you Jan! Appreciate the help!